# How do I get an AS3 AIR desktop app server call to work in localhost using WAMP?

Tags: actionscript-3, localhost, wamp

When talking with the production server from my AIR dekstop app, I successfully get back JSON objects, which I then successfully decode like so:

```
private function completeFunc(event:Event)
{trace("LOGIN RETURN: "+event.target.data);         
        var returnedSettings:Object = JSON.parse(event.target.data);
```

For context, the php page that the app talks with is at:

```
public_html/s/login.php
```

and that page contains

```
<$php 

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../app/login.php';

?>
```

...which calls a php page located above root to run the login and return the JSON.

Works fine. So far, so good.

However, running the same on localhost returns this string back to the AIR app:

```
<$php 

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../app/login.php';

?>
```

Why is that, and how do I make it behave?

The paths for WAMP are set up ok, as I have an updater controller in that AIR desktop app that successfully runs when the app starts.

Thank you

Comment: There are two possible reasons for such a problem to appear: 1) Your WAMP is not configured properly so it processes **PHP** script as if they are plain text files (just outputs their content rather than executing them) or 2) You are accessing the **PHP** file in a way, other than **HTTP** or **HTTPS** protocol, so it is not at all processed by your **WAMP**, but probably accessed as a local drive file (local drive and localhost are different entities).

Comment: Thanks @Organis - WAMP is running other php scripts fine, so it might be the second option. The URL requests starts with http : / / localhost (had to space it out here so SO would show it), but is there something else I need to set up in the AS3 to get it to see local php scripts as php and not just files? Thank you.

Comment: Well, no, if the **URL** specifically states the **HTTP** protocol and gets an answer (meaning **HTTP 200 OK** status rather than any error), that means the problem is not exactly on the client side. If you say that the same **URL** accessed via browser produces the expected answer, but not from the **AIR** app, that means the request is missing something. Headers, cookies, maybe **HTTPS** instead of **HTTP**.

Comment: If I hard code the url with  https :// localhost, I get a 2023 stream error. http :// localhost gives the error I posted about. Forgive my ignorance - I have little knowledge re headers. What sort of header should I be sending with the URLRequest please?

Comment: Sorry, you're on your own in this fight. I'm a **Flash** and **AS1/2/3** veteran, not a network protocols' wizard.

Comment: @Shaun Instead of `http://localhost` try as `http://127.0.0.1` or whatever your localhost IP number is.